# In React ComponenetDidUpdate() lifecycle method gets called multiple times in render prop pattern

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, jsx, react-tsx

I am trying to use render prop pattern to have better code reusability, to do so I am following render prop component (R) which contains lifecycle methods as well a clickHandler from FC (F) which does some processing and updates the redux store. 
I am using render component (R) inside (A) component 3 times with different props. As soon as I use clickHandler from FC it invokes method from render prop component(R) and update the store, but componentDidUpdate() method in render prop component(R) also gets called 3 times which should not happen, it should been called only once. There's no way to know and get which clickHandler updated the store.

ComponentDidUpdate and handleUpload in render prop component(R)

```
/**
 * @remarks
 * call the `{uploadApiDispatcher}` with upload type and required params
 */
    handleUpload() {
        const { uploadApiDispatcher, uploadType } = this.props;
        const params: IUploadApiActionProp = {
            data: { name: 'sanjose' },
            fileIds: [1],
            uploadType,
        };
        uploadApiDispatcher(params);
    }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const { remarks, uploadErrorMessage, uploading, uploadType } = this.props
        if(uploadType !== prevProps.uploadType){
            if (!uploading && remarks && remarks.length) {
            }
            if (!uploading && uploadErrorMessage) {
                message.error(uploadErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

render prop function (UploadRender) use in component (A)

```
<Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={8} xl={6}>
                                    <UploadRender
                                        render={props => (
                                            <UploadCard
                                                title="Upload admin users"
                                                subtitle="This will upload the admin users"
                                                {...props}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                        uploadType={uploadTypes.UPLOADADMINUSERS}
                                    />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={8} xl={6}>

                                    <UploadRender
                                        render={props => (
                                            <UploadCard
                                                title="Upload admin group"
                                                subtitle="This will upload the admin groups"
                                                {...props}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                        uploadType={uploadTypes.UPLOADADMINGROUPS}
                                    />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={8} xl={6}>

                                    <UploadRender
                                        render={props => (
                                            <UploadCard
                                                title="Upload internal users"
                                                subtitle="This will upload the internal users"
                                                {...props}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                        uploadType={uploadTypes.UPLOADINTERNAL}
                                    />
                            </Col>
```

Please help me to understand componentDidUpdate is getting called multiple times and how can I get to know which clickHandler gets called.

Comment: Maybe clickHandler will probably update the Props on (A). So each UploadRender in there has been updated to call componentDidUpdate, so maybe three calls are made.

Comment: @bkm412 I understand why you came with that assumption, but my component (A) is not connected to any store or expecting any props to render. So I cant think any reason for A to reload.